# How to eliminate or sanitize Nicedit

Tags: mysql, nicedit

I have a problem on my nicedit that once it is save there are some added html tags and I try to remove them using this code:

```
$article = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($article))
```

The `$article` is the name of my nicedit textarea and once I save it there are still some html tags save on mysql.

There is another way for removing these html tags? or is my code not right?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at http://htmlpurifier.org/. I use it to control the output generated by nicEdit in order to keep the formatting within certain limits.

The main reason why I use this is, is to deal with the case when people paste something into nicEdit, either from a MS Word document, or other website.